# Rounding the edges of a stroke in bezier path circle in swift

Tags: ios, swift, uibezierpath

I'm trying to draw a circle using `UIBezierPath(ovalInRect: CGRectMake())`. Then I'll change the `strokeEnd` property. When this happens, either end of the circular line have sharp corners. Is there any way to round out these corners?

[image](I would like to make the beginning and end of this line curved)

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Assuming you are using a `CAShapeLayer` to draw this, just set the `lineCap`, e.g.:

```
layer.lineCap = .round
```

Comment: Please would you take a look at this for me http://stackoverflow.com/questions/44062346/how-to-create-a-circle-with-rounded-ends-for-each-quadrant. I've been trying to solve it for a while

Answer (score 3):

For drawRect based solutions use lineCapStyle

`let path = UIBezierPath(...)
path.lineCapStyle = .round`