# Drawing an arc incorrectly leaves flat edges

Tags: ios, swift, uibezierpath

I am having an issue with the arc drawing of a UIBezierPath on IOS.

Whilst I get the semblance of an arc, as can be seen from the image, the top, and two sides have flat edges.

The code I am using looks like this:

```
    let path2 = UIBezierPath()
    path2.addArc(withCenter: arcCentre, radius: radius, startAngle: arcStart, endAngle: arcEnd, clockwise: false)
    path2.addLine(to: finalPoint)
    path2.close()
    color.set()
    path2.fill()
```

The produced arc is shown in black on the image below.

[image]

Any clues as to why this is so, and how to get a perfectly rounded image?

Comment: How are you drawing the path?  Is it part of a view, or are you adding it as a layer?  I suspect your path is getting clipped.

Comment: as a stroke() on the path from within override func draw(_ rect: CGRect)

Comment: I think you're just hitting the edges of the view.  Make the view larger.

Comment: I don't know that line caps are by default rounded. You can try setting the end caps to rounded as in this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34373781/rounding-the-edges-of-a-stroke-in-bezier-path-circle-in-swift

Comment: @vacawama you are correct about hitting the view edges.  reducing the radius of the arc confirms this.

Comment: you can also set view.clipsToBounds = false or setting view.layer.frame larger i think, as draw(_ rect:) renders into the views layer.